# Number of push and pop operations to evaluate a postfix expression

Tags: c#

I need to evaluate the postfix expression `(A*B)+(C*D/E)`
by reverse polish notation
my question is how many push and pop operations will be needed to evaluate this expression by reverse polish notation
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not a post-fix expression, it's a normal expression.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

If it were in post-fix notation.it would look like this:

```
AB*CD*E/+
```

The algorithm used to arrive at this expression is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

I'll step through it to clarify for `(A*B)+(C*D/E)`

Assume there is an output queue which holds the expression as it is converted to to RPN as well as an operator stack.

1. Push the ( to the operator stack.
2. Place A in the output queue because it is a value.
3. Push * on to the operator stack.
4. Place B in the output queue.
5. Check ); pop the * from the operator stack on to the output queue, pop the left parenthesis off the stack but not into the output queue.
6. Push + on to the operator stack.
7. Push the ( to the operator stack.
8. Place C in the output queue.
9. Push * to the operator stack.
10. Place D in the output queue.
11. Check /. It is the same precedence as *, so pop it from the operator stack to the output queue and push / to the operator stack.
12. Place E in the output queue.
13. Check ). Pop / off the operator stack into the output queue, pop ( into non-existence.
14. Nothing is left to read, so pop all remaining operators off the stack. In this case, it'd just be +.
15. Output all characters in the output queue.

Voila:  `AB*CD*E/+` with a total of 6 pushes and 6 pops from the operator stack if counting parentheses; 4 pushes and pops if only counting the operators.

Hope this helped.